# Changing a boolean through an email with Python/Django

Tags: python, django, email, boolean

I'm wanting to send the user an email so that if they click the first link, it'll change the boolean to true and if the user clicks the second link it'll change the boolean to false.

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    confirmed = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)

confirm_links = 'To confirm this order click here: ' + '\nTo deny this order click here: '
email=EmailMessage('This is the title',  confirm_links, to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put a link in your email that maps to a view

```
confirm_links_html = '<a href="/confirm/">Confirm</a> <a href="/deny/">Deny</a>'
msg = EmailMessage('This is the title',  confirm_links, to=['youremail@gmail.com'])
msg.content_subtype = "html"
```

Your views can then implement the necessary logic.

Make sure to authenticate the user correctly.  You could do this by decorating your views with [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator)